# How to track which Javascript manipulates with a given HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-debugger

I'm trying to understand how a template works. If I'd open one in a browser I will see some elements. But If I'd explore the HTML code - the containers with elements appeared in the browser is just empty. This is simple: that means that those containers manipulated by some JS code. However I tried to find the container ID in all JS files mentioned by the main HTML document and not succeeded.

I think that I need some tool which will allowed me to track the JS which changes the given element (place a break-point or make a HTML change log...).

Is there any useful way to do this thing?

Comment: Chrome dev tools or firebug for firefox!

Comment: @ArtjomB. could you be more precise? I'm using Chrome's dev tools but I didn't find any tool to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `console.log('// your breakpoint text');` in javascript. It will be shown in your browser console. That way you can track javascript execution flow.

But the tracking process depends on you. You have to do it manually. Try placing the `console.log()` from the beginning.

In chrome's dev tool. Find the tab with title "Console". Your breakpoint text will be shown there.

Comment: OK, if I'd know which JS function made the changes I could do this do make sure. But to place `console.log` instruction I need to know where I should place it first.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me all you want is the *Web developer's console*. In Chrome it is available through Ctrl+Alt+J (Cmd instead of Ctrl for Macs) and in Firefox with Ctrl/Cmd+Alt+K. Alternatively, simply find those buttons in the browser's options/settings menu.

Once you have the console open, click the mouse-pointer icon to **manually select any element on the screen** you want for inspection. You can also look at the HTML DOM tree directly on the HTML tab. It's all very visual, interactive and intuitive, so just explore a bit.

Comment: I didn't get your idea. I opened the consol, I can manually select any document element (BTW I didn't get your idea about 'mouse-pointer icon'). Any way: how can I find out which JS function changed the element contents?

Comment: @RomanMatveev do you have the JS code that is changing the element contents? if so, then just find the part in the code that references the element in question. you'll just need to do a search for it in the code in your editor and look at all the functions that manipulate it. otherwise i haven't understood your question.

Comment: I tried to find the reference of desired element in the JS code but failed. This wasn't a surprise as JS can refer to any element by several ways and I will not be able to debug ALL JS code in all files :( Please continue to ask me if something is unclear.

Comment: @RomanMatveev If you don't know where the JS calls are that are modifying your element, you should strip away a few layers of the JS so that you can see what's doing what in an organised, incremental way. accompany this by lots of `console.log(e)`, where `e` is the element in question to see when, where and how it changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use debugger; where you add html to dom and by using the console you can check in realtime how your javascript is running.

Another way is to have alerts which you keep on shifting to the next code execution until it goes away from the DOM